# Easy way to view exposed variables in Twig

Tags: php, twig

I'm looking to implement Twig templates into an in-house framework, replacing XSLT templates.

Currently the front-end developers work purely in HTML, CSS & Javascript and only know what data has been exposed to the view from PHP because the framework allows them to view the XML before the XSLT merge takes place.

Is there anything existing for Twig that would allow me to render the variables exposed for a page in a pretty fashion? I've scoured the web and the docs but I can't find anything currently.

Comment: {{dump()}} should do it

Comment: ^ Be sure the debug extension is enabled though

Comment: {{dump()}} does display the data, but not in a particularly pretty way?

Comment: Install xdebug or customize twig and add an extra function that implements a "pretty" print